# How else could I iterate through the results of a cts.search() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I have MarkLogic 9 on my database.

I am trying to iterate through the results of a cts.search() using JavaScript.

I have tried using `Array.from()` and `toArray()`, and although they both work, they take quite some time for a large result set size.

I am looking for an iteration method that would be faster than the 2 mentioned above.

Comment: There is always a *for…* loop, which is at least as fast as array iteration and doesn't require any preprocessing.

Comment: I have just realised that the result set is of type Sequence.

I have tried for loops and cannot seem to retrieve any of the values.

Answer (score 1):

The way to iterate lazily through search results and Sequences in general is by using the for...of construct, as described in our JS Reference guide:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_59096

```
for (const doc of cts.search(cts.trueQuery())) {
  //...
}
```

Mind though that might still not perform well if you are trying to query the entire database, and are simply returning too much output. It is probably wise to consider paging through your results.

A good way of doing so is by using our JSearch library. You can read more about it in our Search Developer guide:

https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/search-dev/javascript

HTH!